# How to change params function names in statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, statistics, statsmodels

I wanted to see if there was a way to change the output names when using the 'params' for the intercept and independent variable. The goal is to put it into a data frame to use later. I know you can change the xnames when using
model.summary(yname="Status", xname=['Alpha', 'Beta'], title='Regression') but I only want the params not the whole summary.

Here is the output

```
Intercept    125.682063
SP50          -0.288299
dtype: float64
```

Here is what I want to change it to

```
Alpha        125.682063
Beta         -0.288299
dtype: float64
```

Here is the code

```
df = pd.read_excel("dataset\Special_Proj.xlsx") 
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%y')
tickers = ['FDX', 'BRK', 'MSFT', 'NVDA', 'INTC', 'AMD', 'JPM', 'T', 'AAPL', 'AMZN', 'GS']

def rolling_regression_stats():
    first52 = df[(df['Date'] <= '2000-12-22')]

    for t in tickers:
        model = smf.ols(f'{t} ~ SP50', data=first52).fit()
        coef_and_intercept = model.params
        print(coef_and_intercept,'\n\n')
        

rolling_regression_stats()
```

Overall, Here is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: Table of Alphas and Betas of Tickers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` accessor returns `pandas.Series`, so you can work with it like you usually work with series. Specifically in your code all you need to do is to work with this line:

```
coef_and_intercept = model.params.set_axis(['Alpha', 'Beta'])
```

Comment: When using reindex, It does change the names, but I get NaN Values

Comment: Edited the answer, should be using `set_axis` instead.